# Add webview into linearlayout android

Tags: android, webview

I want to add view into my main view....

my main.xml file...

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dynamicview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.28"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

I have another layout file call complete.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I want to add this web view into linearlayout....it means I want to inflate webview into my mainactivity...

I used the following method...

```
LinearLayout dynamic=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dynamicview);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View v = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.complete, null);
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        v.getRootView();
        dynamic.addView(v);
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

but this doesn't work. if this is correct then color must be change...but nothing happened. pls help me.. I'm stuck with this...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
LinearLayout dynamic=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dynamicview);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View v = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.complete, null);

WebView wv = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        v.getRootView();
        dynamic.addView(v);
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

You were trying to change the colour of the `FrameLayout` which has been filled by `WebView` therefore the green colour won't be visible. Instead, you have to change the colour of the `WebView`.